# How does a woocommerce plugin valid for 1 website validate it is being installed in 1 website only

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

Recently, i was looking to buy a WooCommerce plugin and it had plans for using the plugin on various websites. I haven't bought any plugin before. So, I was wondering how does the plugin knows where it is being installed. Is there any way in which the plugin developer keeps a track of the installs done on different websites after the plugin has been bought? What would be the issue if I buy for use on 1 website and use it on 10 other websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know that plugins having subscription for N number of sites, come up with the License Key. So obviously they will store your site info easily and they will use the same data to cross check whether the same activation key has been activate on multiple domain or not.

BTW as a developer point of view, once can use the same plugin by doing some customisation related to activation module, but that will not be a good idea to get updates for that specific plugin.

You can check related article from Woocommerce by [clicking here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/frequently-asked-questions/#subscription-number-sites)

Comment: I guess the link answers all my question. Thanks for the reply @Momin

Answer (score 0):

The plug-in developers can track the number of installations with the `key license` (Limited to 1 the most of the time)